# WooCommerce cart.php display backorder message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to display a message under a product in the cart. If the product is on backorder it displays a backorder notification, so I want it to display another message when there is no backorder notification to display.

The code I've tried is:

```
// Backorder notification
if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
    echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available in 3-5 Working Days', 'teencode' ) '</p>';
}
else; {
    echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available Next Day', 'teencode' ) '</p>';
}
```

However, when viewing the cart it's not displaying the message.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

May be you should try this custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_before_cart`** based on your code *(conditions)* to display your custom notifications. There was a lot of little mistakes in your code.

Here is that code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'custom_backorders_notifications' );
function custom_backorders_notifications(){

    $backorders_notification = false;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ):
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id']; // get the product ID for the current cart item
        $item_qty = $cart_item['quantity']; // get the cart item quantity
        $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']); // get the $product OBJECT

        // Backorder notification with your existing (untested) condition
        if ( $product->backorders_require_notification() && $product->is_on_backorder( $item_qty ) ){
            $backorders_notification = true;
            break;
        }

    endforeach;

    if ( $backorders_notification )
        echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( "Available in 3-5 Working Days", "teencode" ) . '</p>';
    else
        echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( "Available Next Day", "teencode" ) . '</p>';
}
```

This code is tested and works.

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*